# Running stored procedure with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, stored-procedures

I am trying to make vba code to run stored procedures, but I am keep getting an error at the last line.
The error is

"An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as ""or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name."

Looks like that is telling me I have a syntax error at the last line. How can I fix this error?

```
 Sub Button_Update()
    'TRUSTED CONNECTION
        On Error GoTo errH
        Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strPath As String
        Dim intImportRow As Integer
        Dim CID, LastID As String
        Dim RDate As Variant
        Dim strRecordID As Integer
        Dim server, username, Password, table, database As String


    If MsgBox("Do you want to update this line?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

        With Sheets("User Input")

                server = "wesrtednt-prod"
                table = "pr_Load"
                database = "Prod"



                If con.State <> 1 Then

                   con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                    'con.Open

                End If
                'this is the TRUSTED connection string

                Set rs.ActiveConnection = con


                'set first row with records to import
                intImportRow = 2

                Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
                CID= .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
                    RDate = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
                    LastID= .Cells(intImportRow, 3)

    If RDate = "" Then RDate = Null



    con.Execute "pr_Load'" & CID& "','" & RDate & "'"""
```

Comment: What data type are the parameters ?

Comment: CID is a int and RDate is a date type data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a space between the procedure name and the first parameter "pr_Load'" & CID. The integer parameter doesn't need quotes, nor does the NULL, and the date is probable best formatted yyyy-mm-dd. For example

```
With Sheets("User Input")
    Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
        
        CID = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
        rdate = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
   
        sql = "pr_load " & CID
        If rdate = "" Then
            sql = sql & ",NULL"
        Else
            sql = sql & ",'" & Format(rdate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
        End If
        Debug.Print intImportRow, sql
        con.Execute sql
        intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
    Loop
End With
```

If you want to use parameters then try

```
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "pr_load"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adDate, adParamInput)
End With

Dim intImportRow As Long, CID As Integer, rdate As Date, sqldate As String
intImportRow = 2
With Sheets("User Input")
    Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
        
        CID = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
        rdate = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
        
        cmd.Parameters(0).Value = CID
        If rdate = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = Null
            sqldate = "NULL"
        Else
            cmd.Parameters(1).Value = rdate
            sqldate = Format(rdate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        End If
        
        Debug.Print intImportRow, CID, sqldate
        cmd.Execute
        
        intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as `CID&` being `CID &`, but I would think you would already be getting a syntax error the way it is. Anyway, you should consider using an ADODB.Command object instead.

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "pr_Load"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("CID", adInteger, adParamInput, CID)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RDate", adDate, adParamInput, Format$(RDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Hmm it saying "Procedure or function 'pr_Load' expects parameter '@CID', which was not supplied." I replaced with last line and getting this error message.

Comment: Can you post at least the header part of your stored procedure?

Comment: I forgot to add the values to the createparameter method. I fixed it.