# Executing an SQL Server stored procedure using VBA in Excel and passing a variable

Tags: excel, vba, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to execute an SQL Server stored procedure using VBA in Excel whilst passing a stored procedure.

My stored procedure code is as follows:

```
update [ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5].[dbo].[Invoice] set Is3rdPartyPosted = 0 where DocumentId = @document_no
```

My VBA Code is as follows:

```
Sub reverse_posted()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long
i = InputBox("Invoice Number to be re-posted")
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ashcourt_app1;Initial Catalog=ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "ashcourt_balfour_reverse_posting" & i
Set Rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

My VBA is very rusty so apologies. Essentially I am trying to pass the contents of the i variable to the parameter @document_no in the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At this stage, I get an error stating it cannot find the stored procedure. It is trying to append the value in variable 1 to the stored procedure name

Comment: thanks for the feedback. If you're referring to the line cmd.CommandText = "ashcourt_balfour_reverse_posting" & i, there is already a space between the quotes and the ampasand, and another before the i variable

Comment: `"ashcourt_balfour_reverse_posting " & i` add space inside quoted string or [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515329)

Comment: thanks again. This has generated a syntax error on this line - Set Rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

Comment: Update queries dont return record sets. add line `cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc`  and then just  `cmd.Execute`

Comment: thanks. Nearly there I think. Does this mean I can rem out everything to do with the rs variable? If so, I get syntax error on the cmd.Execute. If I leave them in I still get the syntax error on the Set Rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc) line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter to the command

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub reverse_posted()

    Const PROC = "ashcourt_balfour_reverse_posting"

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, i As Long
    i = InputBox("Invoice Number to be re-posted")
     
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ashcourt_app1;" & _
             "Initial Catalog=ASHCOURT_Weighsoft5;" & _
             "Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = PROC
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adInteger, adParamInput)
        .Execute , i
    End With

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: amazing, thank you so much for that, works a treat.